# Assembly error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, assembly, x86, shellcode

I'm trying to merge this two codes, and it worked well until the moment I tried executing them. First one:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {

__asm__("jmp 0x1f\npop %si\nmov %esi,0xa(%esi)\nxor %eax,%eax\nmov %eax,0x9(%esi)\nmov
%eax,0x9(%esi)\nmov %eax,0x9(%esi)\nmov %eax,0x9(%esi)\nmovl %eax,0xe(%esi)\nmov $0xb,%al\nmovl %esi,%ebx\nleal 0xa(%esi),%ecx\nleal 0xe(%esi),%edx\nint $0x80\nxorl %ebx,%ebx\nmovl %ebx,%eax\ninc %eax\nint $0x80\ncall -0x24\n.string \"bin/csh\"");
}
```

The second one in assembly:

```
# Vector-asm
.section .data
output:
.asciz “Current value %d\n”
values:
.int 1, 33, 13, 4, 55, 6, 71, 8, 88, 55, 60
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
nop
movl $0, %edi
loop:
Moving Data
movl values(, %edi, 4), %eax
pushl %eax
pushl $output
call printf
addl $8, %esp
inc %edi
cmpl $11, %edi
jne loop
movl $0, %ebx
movl $1, %eax
int $0x80
```

I did try putting the 2 programs together. My intention was to show the values inside my vector in the `/bin/sh` or `/bin/csh` shell:

```
#include <stdio.h>




int main() {

__asm__(".section .data\noutput:\n.asciz \"Current value %d\\n\"\nvalues:\n.int 1, 33, 13, 4, 55, 6, 71, 8, 88, 55, 60\n.section .text\n_start:\nnop\nmovl $0, %edi\nloop:\nmovl values(, %edi, 4), %eax\npushq %rax\npushq $output\ncall printf\naddl $8, %esp\ninc %edi\ncmpl $11, %edi\njne loop\npushq $0x68732f2f\npushq $0x6e69622f\nmovl %esp,%ebx\npushq %rbx\npushq %rax\nmovl %esp,%ecx\nmovb $0x0b,%al\nint $0x80\n");

return 0;
}
```

Sorry for the Inline assembly. But this is the only way I was capable of compile.
None of them worked out. I receive Assembly error: Segmentation fault (core dumped) when I try to execute any of those two. I'm using a 64 bit system and I already tried the same on x86-32 bits. I didn't worked out. I'm gonna provide more information pretty soon. Someone knows what's going on?

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit **Linux** system?  Because this asm uses Linux `int 0x80` system calls.  If you're using WSL, that requires WSL2.

Comment: `movl %esp,%ecx` won't work on a typical 64 bit system. Also your second piece of code is 32 bit. The `pushq` instructions after one another won't do what you think either, since those put 64 bits (sign extended) onto the stack so your strings will be padded.

Comment: Wait a minute, the final code block has `pushq %rax`, but it's still using the `int $0x80` 32-bit system-call interface for system calls that take addresses, with stack addresses that don't fit in 32 bits.  So it can't work anywhere.  [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730)

Comment: Yes for sure. I'm using Linux, more specific: Ubuntu. It's an AMD 64 Bit System, but i had the same problem on Intel 32 bit.

Comment: `jmp 0x1f` is a jump to absolute address `0x0000001f`.  That's definitely not what you want.  Put a label on the jump target and jump to that label.  Like `foo:` and `jmp foo`.  Or `1:` and `jmp 1f` (without the 0x, so it's a jump to the next `1` label in the Forward direction.)

Comment: Having all the asm jammed onto one line is basically unreadable.  Split up the `"long string"` into `"foo\n"` and `"bar\n"` lines with line breaks in the source outside the double-quotes.  (C will paste the string literals together into one long string literal as an early step in compiling, so it's equivalent.)